# React Native: How to use `./gradlew build` command to test for deprecated features

Tags: gradle, react-native, gradlew

In my React Native app, I ran `npx react-native run-android` and it gave me the error `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.`. It then says `Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings`. Is `--warning-mode all` an options to the `./gradlew build` command? And if so, do I just run `./gradlew build` in my project root and then see what the deprecation warnings are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `./gradlew -h` gives me the following as part of the output:

> --warning-mode            Specifies which mode of warnings to generate. Values are 'all', 'summary'(default) or 'none'

You'll want to run `./gradlew build --warning-mode all` in the android directory.

That being said, the default summary probably gives you the info you need already. It's most likely related to `compile` being used in the build files of one or more of your third-party dependencies.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean about compile with the third-party dependencies? I don't know what `compile` is.

Comment: If you look in android/app/build.gradle, you should see dependencies listed in the form `implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'`. Older versions of gradle used the form `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'` which has been deprecated. Your project is likely fine, but you may be using npm packages that contain gradle dependencies declared with the old syntax

Comment: Understood, I'll look into that. Would the best solution be to just upgrade those packages?

Comment: Sure enough, I got `WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'` for one package, and `The maven plugin has been deprecated` in another. I was able to build the project from Android Studio without any errors though. Any idea why this would work but running `react-native run-android` would cite these errors?

Comment: My guess is that whatever arguments Android Studio passes to the build command silences warnings. I wouldn't worry too much about these particular warnings, though. Just sort of something you get used to with React Native and open source Android libraries

Comment: Ok understood. I checked and I do have the latest version of the library that was throwing the `compile` error, so I'm assuming that's not a breaking error. I'm keep digging. Thanks!